# How do I migrate paragraph translations?

Tags: 8, migrations

So I am trying to migrate paragraphs from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. I have created 3 yaml for the same and execute them in below order:

- Paragraph YAML (migrate_plus.migration.paragraph_latest_story.yml)
- Node YAML (migrate_plus.migration.pp.yml)
- Node Translation YAML (migrate_plus.migration.pp_translation.yml)

Migrations for paragraphs works fine until I run *Node Translation YAML*. When I run translation for node it overrides existing paragraph values with the translated one. Below is my code:

**Latest Story Paragraph YAML:**

```
id: paragraph_latest_story
label: 'Paragraph Migration - Latest Story'
migration_group: custom
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 7
  - Paragraph
  - Field Collection
source:
  plugin: d7_paragraphs_item
  bundle: latest_story
  field_name: field_latest_story
  new_revisions: true
process:
  langcode: langcode
  # default_langcode: default_langcode
  # revision_translation_affected: revision_translation_affected
  # content_translation_source: content_translation_source
  field_card_title:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_card_title
    process:
      value: value
    revision_id: revision_id
  field_story_template_selector:
    plugin: sub_process
    source: field_story_template_selector
    process:
      value: value
    revision_id: revision_id
destination:
  plugin: 'entity_reference_revisions:paragraph'
  default_bundle: latest_story
migration_dependencies:
  required: {}
  optional: {}
```

**Node YAML**

```
id: ct_pp
label: 'Migration Content Type: PP'
audit: true
migration_group: custom
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 7
  - Content
  - Domain
  - Workbench
  - Base
deriver: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeDeriver
source:
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: ct_pp
  constants:
      field_collection_list:
        - 'field_latest_story'
process:
  nid: tnid
  type: type
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    source: language
    default_value: "und"
  title: title
  uid: node_uid
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  promote: promote
  sticky: sticky
  revision_uid: revision_uid
  revision_log: log
  revision_timestamp: timestamp
  field_banner_sub_title:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_banner_sub_title
  field_latest_story:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: field_latest_story
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: paragraph_latest_story
      no_stub: true
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      process:
        target_id: '0'
        target_revision_id: '1'
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
migration_dependencies:
  required: {}
```

**Node Translation YAML**

```
id: ct_pp_translation
label: 'Migration Content Type: PP - Translation'
audit: true
migration_group: custom
migration_tags:
  - Drupal 7
  - Content
  - Domain
  - Workbench
  - translation
  - Multilingual
class: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeTranslation
deriver: Drupal\node\Plugin\migrate\D7NodeDeriver
source:
  plugin: d7_node
  node_type: ct_pp
  translations: true
  constants:
      field_collection_list:
        - 'field_latest_story'
process:
  content_translation_source: source_langcode
  nid:
    plugin: migration
    source: tnid
    migration: ct_pp
  type: type
  langcode:
    plugin: default_value
    source: language
    default_value: "und"
  title: title
  uid: node_uid
  status: status
  created: created
  changed: changed
  promote: promote
  sticky: sticky
  revision_uid: revision_uid
  revision_log: log
  revision_timestamp: timestamp
  field_banner_sub_title:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: field_banner_sub_title
  field_latest_story:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: process
      source: field_latest_story
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: paragraph_latest_story
      no_stub: true
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      process:
        target_id: '0'
        target_revision_id: '1'
destination:
  plugin: entity:node
  translations: true
migration_dependencies:
  required: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know how it was in 2020.
But it is possible with latest paragraph module and patches from https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs/issues/3160679.
All steps I've just described in this issue. Note: I show example in a context of d7 -> d9 migration.

But shortly.

The main problem is that paragraph translations imported with different ids. Paragraph translation record should have same id but different langcode. Let's look into **paragraphs_item_field_data** table.

Good exampe:

```
id      revision_id
84448   86919   contact_fc  de  1   1682686892  157062  node    field_contact_fc    a:0:{}  0   1   en  0   1682686958
84448   86919   contact_fc  en  1   1682686892  157062  node    field_contact_fc    a:0:{}  1   1   und 0   1682686958
```

Bad exampe:

```
id      revision_id
84450   86923   contact_fc  de  1   1682686892  157062  node    field_contact_fc    a:0:{}  0   1   en  0   1682686958
84448   86919   contact_fc  en  1   1682686892  157062  node    field_contact_fc    a:0:{}  1   1   und 0   1682686958
```

You need:

- paragraph source tanslation config
- paragraph translations config
- node source translation config
- node translations config

Note: import them in right order.

Nowadays we use **paragraphs_lookup** plugin in node migrations to find correct paragraph.
Field mapping example:

```
  field_contact_fc:
    -
      plugin: sub_process
      source: field_contact_fc
      process:
        target_id:
          -
            plugin: paragraphs_lookup
            tags: 'Field Collection Content'
            source: value
            no_stub: true
          -
            plugin: extract
            index:
              - id
        target_revision_id:
          -
            plugin: paragraphs_lookup
            no_stub: true
            tags:
              - 'Field Collection Revisions Content'
              - 'Field Collection Content'
            tag_ids:
              'Field Collection Revisions Content':
                - revision_id
              'Field Collection Content':
                - value
          -
            plugin: extract
            index:
              - revision_id
```